# Migrating user db to Subversion Edge

Tags: svn, collabnet

I moved a repository from an old server to a new copy of Subversion Edge. I had existing authentication and authorization files that were brought over, but was unable to determine how to integrate those into the Edge product. I modified the httpd conf file by hand to use those existing user files, but this means that I can't manage users in the web interface. There are some references to hsql and I can't figure out where the superadmin credential is stored, but it works currently. Can I get some guidance on how to manage user databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is information on migrating to Subversion Edge here:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/MigrationPath

It explains why User Accounts cannot be migrated:

**User Accounts**

If you are currently using LDAP, then this process is pretty simple. Just enter the LDAP configuration into Subversion Edge under Administration -> Authentication. If your existing LDAP configuration is more complicated than what Subversion Edge supports, you may need to alter the Apache Configuration. See the next section.

If you are using an Apache password file you have some options:

1. Re-create the user accounts in Subversion Edge. This has the
   advantage of making the future administration easier. Users can
   login to Subversion Edge and change their own passwords, and
   administration can take place from the console.
2. Copy your existing file to [CSVN_HOME]/data/conf/svn_auth_file. This will immediately
   transfer the SVN credentials but not create accounts for them in
   Subversion Edge. You can then gradually enter the user accounts into
   Subversion Edge when password or other changes are needed. When you
   create a user in Subversion Edge, the Apache/SVN password will be
   reset to what you provide when creating the account. The user can
   then login and change it.

NOTE: Apache passwords are a one-way hash for security reasons, so there is no way to extract the current password and create a Subversion Edge user account.

Finally, if you are using some other user account system, then you either need to switch to the ones we provide in Subversion Edge or customize the Apache Configuration.